# Почему «В устной речи», но «НА письме»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Пример использования:

> В одних случаях окончание *-ов* в форме родительного падежа
> множественного числа существительных мужского рода перестало
> использоваться не только **в устной речи**, но и **на письме**:
> «победил» вариант с нулевым окончанием.
>
> *[Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно. Д. Э. Розэнталь]*

И в том и в том случае подразумевается речевая деятельность: устная или письменная. Однако в одном случае используется предлог «в», а в другом «на».

Предлог «в» используется при указании на область деятельности:

> 2. Употр. при обозначении явлений, **представляющих собой область деятельности**, состояние кого-н. *Вовлечь в работу. Весь день в работе. Впасть в сомнение. Погрузиться в глубокое раздумье.*
>
> *[Толковый словарь C. И. Ожегова]*

Правильней было бы «в устной речи» (в процессе говорения) и «в письме» (в процессе писания).

---

Предлог «на» больше имеет отношение к месту деятельности, чем к процессу.

> 2. *(на) что и (на) чём.* **Употр. при обозначении места**, области или времени деятельности. *Орудие на позиции. Выйти на позицию. Быть на работе. Идти на работу. Быть на собрании. Вынести вопрос на собрание. Решить на пленуме. Вынести вопрос на пленум. Встреча на будущей неделе. Отложить на будущую неделю. Быть на выставке. Идти на выставку.*
>
> *[Толковый словарь C. И. Ожегова]*

Быть на работе (место), быть в работе (процесс).

---

Почему «**на** письме»? Ведь письмо в данном случае «процесс писания».

Получается:

*«…перестало использоваться не только **в устной речи**, но и **на письме**…»*;

другими словами:

*«…перестало использоваться не только **в процессе говорения**, но и **на процессе писания**…»*.

---

Почему со словом «письмо» используется предлог «на»?

Comment: Такое же: *в теории*, но *на практике*.

Comment: @oleedd Да, тоже интересное наблюдение. Хотя «в практике» также говорят, например: «Это первый случай в моей практике»; когда речь идёт о сравнении теории и практики, говорят, например: «Это в теории, а на практике так не делают». Может, под практикой понимают место действия, поэтому «на».

Comment: "В письме" — это про письмо, которое отправляют. Может, с этим связано (чтоб не было двусмысленности).

Comment: @oleedd Я посмотрел определения предлога «на» в словаре: не понятно, какое определение подходит к письму и к практике. Такое бывает, что предлоги дают разный смысл, например: жить в квартире (своей), жить на квартире (съёмной). Может, вы и правы, что «на» стали использовать, чтоб не было двусмысленности.

Comment: Кому-то непонятно, что, если в конструкции можно использовать как предлог «в», так и предлог «на», то конструкция с «в» имеет вполне конкретный смысл, а с «на» — чуть ли не символический? :) «Что-то у нас в кухне пахнет газом» — «место женщины на кухне». «Дети играют во дворе» — «на дворе холодно». И да: «убираться в квартире» — «жить на квартире у какой-нибудь бабуси».

Comment: @Егор Сальков «„Дети играют во дворе“ — „на дворе холодно“» — можно объяснить тем, что ***в*** указывает на закрытое пространство, внутри которого они играют, а ***на*** — на открытое. Двор, где играют дети, имеет границы, а «на дворе» — означает неограниченное пространство вне дома.

Comment: Я и говорю: «на дворе», в отличие от «во дворе» имеет метафорический смысл и подразумевает всё пространство вне дома, чуть ли не весь мир. Во всяком случае, всю окрестность. Точно так же и «на письме» подразумевает всё написанное вообще, а не конкретное письмо к конкретному адресату.

Comment: @Егор Сальков Возможно, вы правы. Похожую идею высказал в комментарии выше oleedd: _«„В письме“ — это про письмо, которое отправляют. Может, с этим связано (чтоб не было двусмысленности)»_. С другой стороны речь тоже может быть какой-то конкретной. Например: «В этой речи политический лидер подчеркнул что-то». Однако предлог «в» используется независимо от смысла: конкретная речь или речь вообще. 1/2

Comment: @Егор Сальков Может, потому что слово «письмо», как средство связи, широко распатронено, а «письмо», как вид речи, использует лингвистами — возникла необходимость использования разных предлогов. Иначе большинство людей бы думало, что речь идёт про письмо — средство связи. 2/2

Comment: Eagle, так всегда и во всём: конкретный смысл — только для реалий быта, абстрактный — также и для науки.

Comment: «В этой речи политический лидер подчеркнул что-то» — Речь всегда «эта»: для слушателя говорящий всегда присутствует реально и конкретно. А вот написавший для читающего — вживую не присутствует, как правило. Впрочем, человек может читать и собственный текст, — тогда, конечно, писавший всегда присутствует :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Употребление большинства предлогов восходит к их **пространственному значению**, а потом уже распространяется на другие ситуации и  отвлеченные понятия.

***Положи в стол*** (внутрь стола) – ***положи на стол*** (на верхнюю плоскость стола).

В любых случаях эти значения учитываются при образовании предложных сочетаний различного  вида, потом закрепляются в речи и становятся **традиционными**.

2. **Почему устная речь кажется нам «объемной»?** Вероятно,  мы представляем ее неким ментальным пространством, в котором  в виде слов и предложений (в звуковой форме)  реализуются наши мысли. В любом случае это не плоскость.

Потом мы берем плоский лист бумаги и всё сказанное переносим **на него**   – это и определяет выбор предлога НА.

Такая модель **наиболее оптимальна**, поэтому она и утвердилась в грамматике.

Comment: По первому пункту: хорошая мысль. Я проголосовал. По второму: но ведь мы пишем что-то в письме кому-то. Пишем на листе бумаги, но в письме. Однако у меня тоже такая мысль возникла, что возможно, на письме, потому что «**на**писать» — писать на чём-то.

Comment: Пишет в письме — это уже перенос значений, то есть сообщает в письме. Реально же он пишет на бумаге.

Comment: Сложно выбрать чей ответ принять. И вашем, есть разумные мысли и в Егора. В данном случае отдам предпочтение вам, но ответ Егора тоже, я думаю, содержит правильные рассуждения.

Answer (score 2):

Если с каким-то словом можно использовать как предлог «в», так и предлог «на», то конструкция с «в» имеет конкретный смысл, а с «на» — более общий. «Что-то у нас в кухне пахнет газом» — «место женщины на кухне». «Дети играют во дворе» — «на дворе холодно». И т. п. «На дворе», в отличие от «во дворе», подразумевает всё пространство вне дома, чуть ли не весь мир. Во всяком случае, всю окрестность. Точно так же и «**на** письме» подразумевает всё написанное вообще, а не конкретное письмо к конкретному адресату, которое подразумевается, когда говорят или пишут: «**в** своём письме...» Речь конкретна: для слушателя говорящий присутствует реально, «здесь и сейчас». (Если это не запись, — но возможность записывать звук появилась у людей, по историческим меркам, совсем недавно.) Поэтому «**в речи**» (в каждой конкретной речи). А писавший для читающего, как правило, «здесь и сейчас» не присутствует. Поэтому «**на письме**», — если имеется в виду не «в чьём-то письме», а именно «во всех письменных текстах, которые были, есть и будут».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я проголосовал за ваш ответ, однако принял ответ Sharon в этот раз. Мне трудно выбрать в данном случае: и ваш, и её ответы содержат, я думаю, правдоподобные рассуждения. Мне понравилась мысль Sharon касательно, того, что **«употребление большинства предлогов восходит к их пространственному значению»**. У вас похожие рассуждения, но мне объяснение Sharon показалось немного лучше логически построенным. Я, к сожалению, не могу принять оба ответа. Ваш ответ тоже, на мой взгляд, содержит правдоподобную точку зрения.

Comment: «Употребление большинства предлогов восходит к их пространственному значению» — а разве это не дважды два?